# How can I make my Grails domain class behave like a Number?

Tags: grails, groovy, delegates

I have a bunch of Grails domain classes that I want to be able to treat as `Number`s, `Integer`s in particular. For the most part, they are just numeric values with a few extra properties that are used as meta-data. Here's an example:

```
class Score {

    String meaning

    Integer value

    static hasMany = [responses:Response]

    static constraints = {
        meaning blank: false, maxSize: 100, unique: true
        value min: 1, unique: true // Assume we're using a base-1 ranking system, where 1 is the lowest
    }
}
```

I tried to add `@Delegate` to the `value` field, but it didn't seem to have any impact: I still couldn't do `7 + myScore`. All I get is missing method exceptions because Integer doesn't have a signature matching `plus(Score)`.

What is the correct way to go about doing this, since `@Delegate` doesn't seem to work?

<sub>Note: I also have a need to turn my domain classes into various `Collection`s with meta data, but I expect it will be the same solution.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I'm imagining everyone has moved on, now that this question is over a year and a half old, but still, I'm surprised that no one offered up Groovy categories as a solution. Indeed, it seems to me that categories are the most *natural* solution to this problem. Without changing the "Grailsiness" of the original domain class, you can still instill the desired numeric behavior relatively easily.

First define the category class:

```
class ScoreCategory {
    static asType(Score s, Class newClass) {
        switch (newClass) {
            case Integer.class:
            case Integer.TYPE: 
            case Number.class: return s?.value ?: 0
            default: throw new GroovyCastException("Cannot cast to ${newClass}")
        }
    }

    static boolean equals(Score me, def you) {
        you instanceof Score && me as int == you as int
    }

    static Score plus(Score a, b) { plusImpl(a, b) }
    static Score plus(Score a, Number b) { plusImpl(a, b) }
    static Score plus(Number a, Score b) { plusImpl(a, b) }
    private static plusImpl(a, b) { new Score(value: (a as int) + (b as int)) }

    static Score minus(Score a, b) { minusImpl(a, b) }
    static Score minus(Score a, Number b) { minusImpl(a, b) }
    static Score minus(Number a, Score b) { minusImpl(a, b) }
    private static minusImpl(a, b) { a + -b }

    static Score multiply(Score a, Number b) { multImpl(a,b) }
    static Score multiply(Number a, Score b) { multImpl(a,b) }
    private static multImpl(a,b) { new Score(value: (a as int) * (b as int)) }

    static Integer div(Score a, b) { (a as int).intdiv(b as int) }
    static Score div(Score a, Number b) { new Score(value:(a as int).intdiv(b as int)) }

    static Score negative(Score a) { new Score(value: -(a as int)) }
    static Score abs(Score a) { new Score(value: (a as int).abs())}
}
```

Then, at some suitably global place in the application declare the mixins:

```
Number.metaClass.mixin ScoreCategory
Score.metaClass.mixin ScoreCategory
```

After all this, as demonstrated below, `Score` objects should now behave like numeric quantities:

```
def (w, x, y, z) = [54, 78, 21, 32]
def (s1, s2) = [new Score(value:w), new Score(value:x)]

assert (s1 + s2) == new Score(value: w + x)
assert (s1 + y) == new Score(value: w + y)
assert (z + s2) == new Score(value: z + x)
assert (s1 - s2) == new Score(value: w - x)
assert (s1 - y) == new Score(value: w - y)
assert (z - s2) == new Score(value: z - x)
assert (s1 * y) == new Score(value: w * y)
assert (z * s2) == new Score(value: z * x)
assert (s2 / s1) == x.intdiv(w)
assert (s1 / y) == new Score(value: w / y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an overload for the `plus` operator on the `Number` metaclass:

```
Number.metaClass.plus = { Score s -> delegate + s.value }
```

Add this in BootStrap.groovy in your app, or in `doWithDynamicMethods` in a plugin.

**Edit:**

As pointed out in the comments, this doesn't work if the `Score` is on the left side of the operation. Add a `plus` method to the `Score` class to handle that:

```
Number plus(Number n) { value + n }
```

Comment: Is it better to use `.plus << {Score s -> ... }` rather than `=`?

Comment: You'd also need to overload "plus" on the Score object to take a Number and respond correctly.

Comment: Yes, what about new Score(value: 4) + 5?

Answer (score 0):

You answer can be [operator overloding](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operator+Overloading). Here you are overloading the plus method to operate with integers and doubles:

```
class Score {
    ...
    int plus(int otherValue){
        return otherValue + value
    }

    double plus(double otherValue){
        return (value as double) + otherValue
    }

    // And you can avoid my pitfall overriding asType method
    Object asType(Class clazz) {
        if (clazz == Integer) {
            return value         
        }
        else if(class == Double){
            return value as Double
        }         
        else {             
            super.asType(clazz)         
        }     
    }    

}

assert new Score(value: 4) + 15 == 19
assert new Score(value: 4) + 15.32 == 19.32
assert 15.32 + (new Score(value: 4) as Double) == 19.32
assert 15 + (new Score(value: 4) as Integer) == 19
```

Comment: What about `15 + new Score(value: 4)` ?

Answer (score -1):

You can also extend Number.

```
class Score extends Number {
   Integer value

   public int intValue() { return value }
   public double doubleValue() { return value }
   public long longValue() { return value }
   public float floatValue() { return value }
}

Score sc = new Score( value: 5 );

println 10 + sc
```

Comment: *sigh*, a minus vote with no comments.  How can I know what's wrong with the answer? (not that anything is :P)

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but I could have been. You've taken out all the original features of `Score` that were needed to compile it into a Grails domain class.

Comment: I only put what was relevant... The rest of the constraint stuff can be added without affecting the issue at hand.